# laravel redirect with white screen and message "redirecting to..." breaks posts

Tags: apache, redirect, laravel, apache2, mamp

I have been working with Laravel for quite a while, and encountered a problem with MAMP today. I can't track down its roots since I didn't do a composer update or any other software change that could cause it. Anyways, the problem breaks down the login form on my website on localhost (there is no problem in production, or in the same project on WAMP that my friend is using).
The issue makes itself apparent by printing out "redirecting to ..." messages on the screen when a redirect is happening in the application. after submitting my login form I am getting this message and being redirected back to the login page. From what I found on the web the issue might be in the fact that doing redirects somehow kills my post data that should be checked with the login action, thus authentication attempt fails and I am being redirected back to login form. Apparently the error message from auth::attempt is being lost along the way of redirects as well. 
I have encountered [someone](http://laravel.io/forum/04-09-2014-redirectto-in-auth-filter-displays-plain-text-message-redirecting-to-url) facing the same problem and fixing it with nginx, but since I am using mamp with apache2, I couldn't find how to perform the same trick with it. 
No errors are being logged with this issue. Any ideas on how this can be fixed please?

Comment: Hi! I'm getting the same issue and can't find a proper solution anywhere. Any chance you could fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had exactly the same error, and I tried all type of solutions: nginx, filtering, spaces at the end of files.

After several hours, I decided to look for spaces at the end of files again, and that was it: Right after the Auth::attempt, I was setting up a Session variable using a Model that had a line break after ?>

This was causing Laravel to show the "Redirecting to..." message, and because it was shown, the session was lost, so the user was not logged in.

This was a Server error only, on my Localhost it always worked fine with spaces.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I have looked carefully, but none of my models actually have php closing mark (?>) at the end of it. My code there goes like this
`$remember = (Input::has('remember')) ? true : false;
if (Input::has('from')) $from = Input::get('from'); else $from ='';
if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('email'), 'password'=>Input::get('password'),'confirmed' => true), $remember)) {if ($from == 'start') {Redirect::action('HomeController@getStart');
}
return Redirect::action('HomeController@getIndex');
} else {return Redirect::action('UsersController@getLogin')->withInput();
} `

Comment: After debugging three days and outsourcing the issue to a developer and spending around 400 USD the issue was un resolved.
But finally, it got it solved when I found a space before <?php in route/web.php

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect without losing the input with `withInput()`:

```
Redirect::to('form')->withInput(Input::except('password'));
```

Comment: that's what I have been doing - and its working just fine everywhere except my mac. It was working here before today. The thing looks as if it is doing double redirect, and losing input on the second one

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error and tried all the solutions given in the other answers but with no result. After a while I made a discovery the problem was occurring because I had to much logic in my `App::before` filter.

I tried to relocate the logic but that didn't work well either, so the only options I had left was executing the logic after the page load or just remove it and trying to find an other way.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it's because of an erroneous ip specified in one of my nginx server block. When I corrected the ip, the "redirecting to" page no longer occurs and I am successfully redirected.